# Javascript get first and next two digits of a number

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the first and next to digits of a number as an array using regex in JavaScript?

I was doing this :

```
let foo = '1234567'; 

let op = foo.match(/^\d{1}|\d{2}/g)

console.log(op)
```

But this outputs everything even after the third number.

Im trying to get the output as

```
[1,23]
```

Comment: `let op = foo.match(/^(\d)(\d{2})/)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may capture the first and the next two digits into separate captuirng groups:

```js
let foo = '1234567'; 
let op = foo.match(/^(\d)(\d{2})/);
if (op) {
  console.log(op.slice(1));
}
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `(\d)` - captures a digit into Group 1
- `(\d{2})` - captures the second and third digit into Group 2.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pC5a6/1).

Before accessing group values, you should check if there was a match, hence, you might use  a check like `if (op) {...}`. `.slice(1)` is used to get rid of the first value in the array, which is always the whole match value.

If you need to use your regex with alternation and `g` modifier for some reason, you can only make it work with  a lookbehind that is now available in the majority of JavaScript environments:

```js
console.log( '1234567'.match(/^\d|(?<=^\d)\d{2}/g) );
```

Here,

- `^\d` - matches the digit at the start of string
- `|` - or
- `(?<=^\d)\d{2}` - two digits that are preceded with a digit at the start of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pC5a6/2).

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make my original regex stop after the third digit? So I don't need to use split etc.

Comment: @Norman Yes, but with a lookbehind. `let op = foo.match(/^\d|(?<^\d)\d{2}/g)`
`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let foo = '1234567'; // input string
let op = foo.match(/^(\d)(\d{2})/); // regex
let opSliced = op.slice(1); // slice 
console.log(opSliced);
```